# How to redirect user to new page without getting exiting without changes prompt

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and working on somebody else's code, it have a form which was missing a field necessary to store form values on serverside. I added a new hidden input field and set it's value via following code.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="hidden_field" />
    <input type="submit" class='action_button' data-action='save' />
</form>

$('.action_button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#hidden_field').val($(this).data('action');
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

Now form is submitted, data is stored on serverside and in the end of controller it has following code.

```
return redirect(url('home'));
```

Although logic is now working properly, whenever I try to make some changes and submit the form, server side tells the browser to redirect but browser thinks I have unsaved changes so it shows me the prompt to exit without saving or stay. How can I avoid it, without disabling prompts altogether?

Comment: why don't you just change the hidden input when page loads! not when click submit. I think it's a `Js` issue

Comment: because that form has more than one action button and I need to decide before form submit which button was clicked and send an action accordingly.

Comment: what if you use ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was resolved after a long hour of debugging, and error was raising due to some global JS file which had `window.onbeforeunload` for every input button on the page. I am posting this for
anyone else who might face this issue. Make sure you have the click function as follows.

```
$('.action_button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    $('#hidden_field').val($(this).data('action');
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

Comment: For the records, `onbeforeunload` is not and has never been a browser default feature. You won't face the issue in the first place unless you actively add a handler in your code (in this case, it was some other coworker who did).

Answer (score 0):

The browser is showing prompt message, beacuse you are using **post method**. I think that it prompts on firefox, but not on google chrome.

The solution is to change the **post to get** method. Of course if you're posting data you shouldn't do that. You also may try to use some javascript code, but when I was facing very similar problem it did not help.

Comment: I don't think using a get form instead of post is a good idea on a route to accept post request.

Comment: That's not true. You're probably thinking about the "Repost form data" you get when you browse around browser history.

Comment: @Anfal If it has to be a post route then my solution is not good for you. Sometimes people wrongly choose between post and get routes, that's why I suggested you the solution.